# Using jquery plugin send variable to JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I am using a JQuery eventcalendar plugin  from this [website](http://www.vissit.com/projects/eventCalendar/).

Does anybody know how I can send a variable through to JSON so i can filter the data outputted. Can i send it in the link or would i need to use AJAX? Any pointers would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```
<div id="cal"></div>

$("#cal").eventCalendar({
  // link to events json
  eventsjson: 'file.php' 
});
```

**file.php**

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/json');

$var = $_GET["var"];

$sqldata = mysql_query('
SELECT
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_date) AS date,
employee AS title, 
days AS description,
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end_date) AS url
FROM requests WHERE approved = 1
');

$posts = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqldata))
{
    $row['date'] = $row['date'].'000';
    $row['url'] = $row['url'].'000';
    $row['description'] = $row['description'].' Days';
    $posts[] = $row;
}
mysql_free_result($sqldata);
die(json_encode($posts));

?>


function getEvents(limit, year, month, day, direction) {
    var limit = limit || 0;
    var year = year || '';
    var day = day || '';

    // to avoid problem with january (month = 0)

    if (typeof month != 'undefined') {
        var month = month;
    } else {
        var month = '';
    }

    //var month = month || '';
    flags.wrap.find('.eventsCalendar-loading').fadeIn();

    if (eventsOpts.jsonData) {
        // user send a json in the plugin params
        eventsOpts.cacheJson = true;

        flags.eventsJson = eventsOpts.jsonData;
        getEventsData(flags.eventsJson, limit, year, month, day, direction);

    } else if (!eventsOpts.cacheJson || !direction) {
        // first load: load json and save it to future filters
        $.getJSON(eventsOpts.eventsjson + "?limit="+limit+"&year="+year+"&month="+month+"&day="+day, function(data) {
            flags.eventsJson = data; // save data to future filters
            getEventsData(flags.eventsJson, limit, year, month, day, direction);
        }).error(function() { 
            showError("error getting json: ");
        });
    } else {
        // filter previus saved json
        getEventsData(flags.eventsJson, limit, year, month, day, direction);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code of this plugin has:

```
$.getJSON(eventsOpts.eventsjson + "?limit="+limit+"&year="+year+"&month="+month+"&day="+day, function(data)...
```

Meaning if you add a parameter to the link it will not work...

you will need to change the plugin code a bit to test for the existence of parameters and only then add the internal ones, something like:

```
var URL = eventsOpts.eventsjson;
URL += (eventsOpts.eventsjson.indexOf('?') < 0) ? '?' : '&';
URL += "limit="+limit+"&year="+year+"&month="+month+"&day="+day;
$.getJSON(URL, function(data)...
```

Comment: that is defined in a seperate .js, how would i pass my variable through php to this. i have updated the question with the function defined

Comment: What I mean is that the plugin code needs to change so it can accpet the parameter you want to pass to the PHP...

Comment: :) ive sorted it using your method then added parameter to the link, added it in JSON file above and tweaked the jquery.eventCalendar.js for the new param